# C++ Uploading to an FTP server with WinINet

Tags: c++, ftp, wininet

I have been searching for 2 hours now, and I can't seem to figure out how to simply upload a file with an FTP server.

I'd prefer to use WinINet, since I'm new to C++ and Microsoft Visual Studio (I'm not new to programming, just to C++)

All I really need is a working example of how to upload a file with an FTP server. I've been all over the web for the last 2 hours, and I can't find anything.

I've tried a lot of different libraries and stuff, but none seem to work, and a lot are outdated.

Anyways, if you'd share your knowledge, links, or experience about using FTP to upload a file with C++, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks -Alex Benoit

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for lots of example code (which was not hard to find)

Comment: I have been there. I've gone through about 200 different pages..I've read over A LOT of that. I seem to be doing evthing right, but there's just so many approaches, and so many different possible errors.

Comment: If you mean possibl runtime errors (rather than programming errors): Yes, and no different example will solve that. Big parts of the whole Winapi are designed in a way that there are about >100 (at least "a lot") different possible errors per command. About programming errors: If the codes are too confusing, on the same site are diagrams which show the names, order etc. of the core functions that you´ll need. The rest is to read the documentation to this functions to find out about possible parameters, return values etc.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Here's the code I'm using

```
#include <wininet.h> 
#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet")
void FileSubmit()
    {
        HINTERNET hInternet;
        HINTERNET hFtpSession;
        hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
        if (hInternet == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Error: " << GetLastError();
        }
        else
        {
            hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, "server", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "user", "pass", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
            if (hFtpSession == NULL)
            {
                cout << "Error: " << GetLastError();
            }
            else
            {
                if (!FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, "C://file.txt", "/file.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0))
                {
                    cout << "Error: " << GetLastError();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This may not work in windows 7 or below. There's a problem with WinINet. I believe it was actually fixed for Windows 8.1 with last nights update, but that's just a fix for Windows 8.1 unfortunately not Windows 7 as well.

Comment: What problem? I found your answer and was planning to use it!